# Path of charged particle in a uniform magnetic field with an external force

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields

Consider the following:
A negatively charged particle with v travelling to +X on the coordinate system, and enters a magnetic field pointing inward on a paper or -Z, the electron would have a stationary circular path on X and Y plane with a counter-clockwise direction .
Now consider the same scenario, but with an external force (e.g gravity) on the particle with direction of -Y, assuming that the magnetic field didn't exist the particle would have parabolic path identical to the path of trajectory under gravity.
What would the path of the particle if it was experiencing both Lorentz force and an external force like gravity?

Comment: ${\bf F}_{total} ={\bf F}_{Lorentz} + {\bf F}_{gravity} = q({\bf E} + {\bf v}\times{\bf B}) + m{\bf g}$

Answer (score 0):

Turning gravity on is similar to turing the $\mathbf{E}$ field on. So you'll simply get a drift motion in $\mathbf{g}\times\mathbf{B}$ direction with the drift velocity:
$$
\mathbf{v}_{\rm d}=\frac{m}{e}\frac{\mathbf{g}\times\mathbf{B}}{B^2}.
$$

Comment: Hayk Hakobyan: Just to clarify, you mean a drift motion superimposed on the increasing velocity due to gravity?

Comment: If the field $\mathbf{g}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{B}$, then you just have a drift motion with oscillating velocity. No asymptotic behavior. The same, as in case of $\mathbf{E}$ field, but instead of having $\mathbf{F}=e\mathbf{E}$, you have $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{g}$, no difference. On the other hand, if you had a component across $\mathbf{B}$, then you'll get a helix motion.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've already seen this equation in a few papers, but how does this describe the path of the particle? Is the motion helical to the direction of velocity?

Comment: It's a simple well known drift of a guiding center. See here: https://goo.gl/rF09pu.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan If you put  $g=0$ so that there is no gravity, the problem consists of a charged particle travelling along the $x$ axis with initial speed $v$ placed in a uniform magnetic field $B$ along the $z$ direction. The particle will move in a circle with constant speed $v$. However, according to your result it has a drift velocity $\mathbf{v}_{\rm d}=\frac{m}{e}\frac{\mathbf{g}\times\mathbf{B}}{B^2} = {\bf 0}$? Shouldn't $v$ come into the answer? For very weak magnetic fields you should have a particle accelerating in the direction of ${\bf g}$?

Comment: Did you read the article I sent? The drift velocity is __not__ the velocity of the particle itself. It's the velocity of its guiding center. If you have $\mathbf{g}=0$, then $\mathbf{v}_{\rm d}=0$, which means the guiding center is not moving, and you have a simple circular motion.

Comment: In the limit of weak magnetic field the gyroradius becomes large, and you get your parabolic motion.